# Add custom list menu on Posts page in admin panel

Tags: wp-admin

How can i add custom_list as shown in attached screen-shot. I want to list posts having some meta_value . Is there any way of adding this. I am not looking to edit the core files. Please guide me in right way.

[image: Add custom list menu on Posts page in admin panel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `views_{$this->screen->id}` filter in `WP_List_Table::views()`, where screen ID in this case is `edit-post`:

```
function wpse_177655_views( $views ) {
    $custom = sprintf( '<a href="%s"', esc_url( 'edit.php?post_type=post&custom=foobar' ) );
    if ( ! empty( $_GET['custom'] ) && $_GET['custom'] == 'foobar' )
        $custom .= ' class="current"';
    $custom .= '>Custom</a>';

    $views['custom'] = $custom;

    return $views;
}

add_filter( 'views_edit-post', 'wpse_177655_views' );
```

Obviously this is more of an example than an exact solution. You'll also need to hook onto `pre_get_posts` to add the relevant meta query args.